# Determine if NSFetchedResultsController is Empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

What is a good way of determining if a NSFetchedResultsController is empty (contains no entries)? I realize that one could use `fetchedObjects` does this load all results into memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fetchedObjects is an array, and is a good a way as any to check for 0 records.

You could also use

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
if([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] == 0)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Does calling `fetchedObjects` force the NSFetchedResultsController to load all entries into memory?

Comment: I thought the objects are loaded into memory when you call perform fetch. You could create a fetch request with an expression description just for the count of the objects then do the actual fetch if the count is > 0.

Comment: @Greg Not a bad idea for creating a specialized fetch request. Thanks